AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' when using PyPartPicker
Is anyone familiar with the 'AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text' error when trying to search with the PyPartpicker API?`
Even the example code:
from pypartpicker import Scraper

# creates the scraper object
pcpp = Scraper()
# returns a list of Part objects we can iterate through
parts = pcpp.part_search("i7")

# iterates through every part object
for part in parts:
    # prints the name of the part
    print(part.name)

# gets the first product and fetches its URL
first_product_url = parts[0].url
# gets the Product object for the item
product = pcpp.fetch_product(first_product_url)
# prints the product's specs using the specs attribute
print(product.specs)

Returns this error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/workspaces/pcpartpickertest/index.py", line 7, in <module>
    parts = pcpp.part_search("i7")
  File "/home/codespace/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypartpicker/scraper.py", line 232, in part_search
    soup = self.__make_soup(f"{search_link}&page={i + 1}")
  File "/home/codespace/.python/current/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pypartpicker/scraper.py", line 95, in __make_soup
    if "Verification" in soup.find(class_="pageTitle").get_text():
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'

I'm struggling to fing any documentation apart from the offical Github page so if anyone could provide any docs or ideas that would be much appreciated!
I've tried everything, including removing the Search object all together, please help!

Does this answer your question? Why do I get AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'something'?

Yes, this is one of the most common errors that people report. The issue is with the last line of code in the error message, which tells us that it occurs at scraper.py, line 95, in __make_soup.
The key is in the statement:
if "Verification" in soup.find(class_="pageTitle").get_text():

The call to soup.find should return some object reference on which a call to get_text will return some data. But if soup.find does not succeed it does not return any object (in reality it returns None). So the call to get_text is impossible because there is no object to call it from. Which results in the error message:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_text'
And the original place in your code which starts this sequence, is line 7:
parts = pcpp.part_search("i7")

So you need to do some debugging to try to find out why the initial call to soup.find is failing.

@Stylus Well, I wish I was, but in reality I am just a simple programmer. Incidentally, the pypartpicker library should handle this condition rather than crashing your code.
